# Eclipse remote debugging using jumphost

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, ssh, remote-debugging

I have the current setup to connect to a remote machine:

***My local machine(running linux)-> ssh to jump host -> ssh to development machine with tomcat***

What would I need in order to remote debug from the eclipse in my local machine (ubuntu) to the development one. I've researched the matter but found no clear answer yet and eclipse doesn't have configurations for this scenario.

Any help would be really appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I just added this to the tomcat configuration and restarted:

*-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n*

Opened a tunnel like this from my machine:

*ssh myuseronjumphost@jumphostaddress -L 8000:developmentmachine:8000*

The tomcat debug configuration was with Standard (Socket Attach), connection properties Host: localhost, Port:8000

That way it worked perfectly

I solved this a while ago but forgot about the question so I wanted to share in case anyone finds it useful.